# Why 4" and 5" screen not showing images properly

Tags: android, screen, resolution, hdpi, mdpi

I have develop a simple application and compile it with screen resolution 480*800 mdpi emulator.It shows all images perfectly placed on screen.

I have added images only in drawable folder.

But when i try the same application with 480*800 hdpi emulator the images looks big on the screen and all alignment gets distracted.

Do I need the different image size for mdpi and hdpi pixel density for same screen resolution i.e 480*800 also?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. For different screen densities, you should provide appropriately scaled bitmaps.

This way they will look the best on all devices, without Android having to scale them.

This link should provide you with important information to get started:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html